# php shell_exec return null

Tags: php, cmd, command, shell-exec

I want run `php ../cat1/index.php gr_s2/3/gr-n40 1200` command by php.
The shell_exec return NULL as result but when I try that command on cmd, output was shown correctly.

What happen in php and shell_exec ?!

Note: The command with different parameters (Like: `php ../cat1/index.php gr_s2/3/gr-n40 800`) works correctly in both (php and cmd).

Comment: Can you add 2>&1 and the end of the line and check again?

Comment: dear @sergio, Nup! not worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ***note*** in php manual page of ***shell_execute***:

> Note: This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the
>   program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution
>   failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the
>   program exit code is required.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

So your code running with error. Try with **exec**.
If you want, insert your code (or blocks) to be checked.

Comment: Dear @shozdeh, I tried with exec() method an got same resutl...!
There  is no error in code.

Comment: @MasoudNazari check run time limit or memory limit is not reached?!

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by adding user used by web-server to sudoer and run the php command with

```
sudo php ..........
```

To start run this command `sudo visudo`

Add the following line at the end of sudoer file opened

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php
```

But if you whant to execute all commad from php add this line instead of the above `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` which is not recommended

and the run your commands with `sudo php /path/to/you/file.php`

For my case I was running ubuntu 14.04

Have fun please

Comment: I am facing the same problem when I am executing external exe. Windows don't have sudo command